# JTable nicely sized in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel

I had a problem with Java's form. I tried to size my JTable to take the entire space on the JPanel, but it won't. Do you have advice for me about that ? I show you the problem and my code, thanks to all of you.

[image]

And my code here

```
package DisplayingLibrary;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import com.sdz.connection.SdzConnection;

import LibraryDAO.DAO;
import LibraryTable.Ouvrage;
import LibraryTableDAO.OuvrageDAO;

public class DisplayLibrary extends JFrame{

  public DisplayLibrary() {
      this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setTitle("JTable");
      this.setSize(1000, 600);
      this.setBounds(100, 100, 941, 495);
      this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setBounds(10, 11, 712, 434);
      this.getContentPane().add(panel);
      panel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

      JTable table = new JTable();
      JScrollPane tableSP = new JScrollPane(table);

      panel.add(tableSP);


      DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
          Object[] columnsName = new Object[4];
          columnsName[0] = "Id";
          columnsName[1] = "Code Ouvrage";
          columnsName[2] = "Nom ouvrage";
          columnsName[3] = "Nom Auteur";

      model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnsName);
      Object[] rowData = new Object[4];
        DAO<Ouvrage> ouvrageDAO = new OuvrageDAO(SdzConnection.getInstance());
        ArrayList<Ouvrage> ouvrages = ouvrageDAO.getList();
        for(int i = 0; i < ouvrageDAO.getList().size(); i++) {
              rowData[0] = ouvrages.get(i).getId_ouvrage();
              rowData[1] = ouvrages.get(i).getCode_ouvrage();
              rowData[2] = ouvrages.get(i).getNom_ouvrage();
              rowData[3] = ouvrages.get(i).getNom_auteur();
              model.addRow(rowData);
        }
        table.setModel(model);


        //this.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));



  }

  public static void main(String[] args){

      DisplayLibrary dl = new DisplayLibrary();
      dl.setVisible(true);



  }


}
```

I color my Panel with Orange to show you where is the problem, I have to hide all this color. I had add a BorderLayout, or when I want to had a SetLayout(null) to my JPanel to resize my JTable, the JTable dissapear. Thanks you again for your help.

Edit with the help of Camickr

[image]

with the following code

```
this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setTitle("JTable");
      this.setSize(1000, 600);
      this.setBounds(100, 100, 941, 495);




      /*JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setBounds(10, 11, 712, 434);
      this.getContentPane().add(panel);
      panel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);*/

      JTable table = new JTable();
      table.setSize(700, 400);
      JScrollPane tableSP = new JScrollPane(table);
      BorderLayout borlay = new BorderLayout();

      //panel.add(tableSP);
      this.getContentPane().add(tableSP, borlay.CENTER);
      JButton button = new JButton();
      button.setSize(40, 40);
      this.getContentPane().add(button, borlay.LINE_END);
      JButton button_2 = new JButton();
      this.getContentPane().add(button_2, borlay.LINE_END);
```

Comment: Add your table direct to the contentPane. In this case the `BorderLayout`, which is default layout manager for contentPane, will give your table the complete place of the window.

Comment: As said [this documentation page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/awtlayoutmgr-137229.html#BORDER), "Note that when using the BorderLayout, you must add components with either the `add(Component, Object)` method to ensure the components are all added correctly. A common mistake people make is to use `add(Component)`, which can result in some of the components not being visible".

Comment: Also, try `CardLayout`, it sounds like it can work for you.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov something like that ? table.setLayout(new CardLayout()); or panel.add(tableSP, new CardLayout()); ?

Comment: @UnagiV, yes, try one of those, see if it helps.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov i try both but nothing is working.

Comment: This has nothing to do with a CardLayout. Just use the default BorderLayout as has already been suggested. Of course in order for the BorderLayout to work you need to get rid of all the `setLayout( null )` statements. Don't use a null layout!!! Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy i try that solution, the problem is the Jtable take all the place in the contentPane, that's why i made  JPanel to have one side (about 75% of the window) and a other Panel to have button and combobox.

Comment: @camickr thanks, i'll try that

Answer (score 1):

> the problem is the Jtable take all the place in the contentPane, that's why i made JPanel to have one side (about 75% of the window) and a other Panel to have button and combobox.

So you add the table to the `CENTER` and the panel to the `LINE_END` area of the `BorderLayout`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: i try with your way, it's ok i succeed to add button but i can't resize the button, and when i try to add a other one it's not working. I need to add a other contentPane and do the same method with my button and combobox ? Anyway thanks for that helpful advices.

Comment: PS: i've add the new window and the new code in my first post.

Comment: If you want two buttons on the right side then you need to 1) create a panel, 2) add the buttons to this panel, 3) add the panel to the frame.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, i succeed!with your help and also because i used setSize instead of setPreferredSize

Comment: @UnagiV, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept' the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: You should not be using setSize(). It is the job of the layout manager to determine the size of a component. If set size works then then that means you are using a null layout. Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.